# ERROR C2143: Syntax error: missing ';' before '<' C++

Tags: c++

I am having trouble in my C++ code where I have to make a binary heap. It works fine as long as I had the "main" function inside of my "MyHeap.h" file but my professor wants it to run in a separate test file. For some reason the code doesn't want to run whenever I try to put the main function outside of the "MyHeap.h" file. When it runs I get the following error:

```
error C2143: syntax error: missing';' before '<'
```

I looked at my code and this is where it says there is an error but I can't see anything.

```
 // MyHeap.h
#ifndef _MYHEAP_H
#define _MYHEAP_H

#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

class Heap {
public:
    Heap();
    ~Heap();
    void insert(int element);
    int deletemax();
    void print();
    int size() { return heap.size(); }
private:
    int left(int parent);
    int right(int parent);
    int parent(int child);
    void heapifyup(int index);
    void heapifydown(int index);
private:
    vector<int> heap;
};

#endif // _MYHEAP_H
```

So like I said whenever I have the the `int main` function right after the private class, it will work just fine. Now when I implement it into my test file which is this:

```
#include "MyHeap.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    // Create the heap
    Heap* myheap = new Heap();
    myheap->insert(25);
    myheap->print();
    myheap->insert(75);
    myheap->print();
    myheap->insert(100);
    myheap->print();
    myheap->deletemax();
    myheap->print();
    myheap->insert(500);
    myheap->print();
    return 0;
}
```

It keeps popping up the errors, any ideas on I could go about fixing this problem so that my code can run from a test file?

Comment: You should at least highlight (e.g. using a comment), where this error occurs in your code sample.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `std::vector` instead of `vector`.

The compiler is complaining it doesn't know about `vector`.

Since it lives in `std` namespace, the safest solution is to prefix with `std`.